# Change Timeout in Table Adapter Configuration Wizard Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, timeout, tableadapter

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Professional and MySQL 5.0.67. Both of the programs running in 32-bit OS.
When I add new Table Adapter using **Table Adapter Configuration Wizard**, in the Choose a Command Type section, I click **Use existing store procedures**. After I click the Next button, I always get Timeout Expired error in around 30 seconds progress.

[Timeout Expired image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prkgw.jpg)

I have already unchecked **Cancel long running query** in menu Tools -> Options -> Database Tools -> Query and Views Designers.

I have also already unchecked **Override connection string time-out value for table designer updates** in menu Tools -> Options -> Database Tools -> Table and Database Designers.

In my MySQL connection string, I have also already set the Connection Timeout value to 1000.

But the result still same. The Timeout Expired error appear in around 30 seconds.

Any solution for me to set the timeout become longer or maybe no timeout? Because I have about 1800 MySQL procedures in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem. I change defaultcommandtimeout value to more than 30 seconds in MySQL connection string. I never get Timeout Expired anymore.